# Visual Studio wants to clone my GIT repo when it's already there

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

So I've been working on my project and then at some point Visual Studio has decided that I haven't cloned my repo and wants to do it again.

[image]

If I open my solution directly from the File | Open | Project/Solution then Team Explorer doesn't seem to know it's a Team Services project and is missing options.

[image]

Is there any way to reconnect these?  I keep having to blow away my local repo and re-clone it from the remote.  That's pretty unhelpful if I have locally committed changes that I need to push.

Comment: I copied the current one out, let vs do its thing, then copied the current one back over the vs-replicated one.  Prob not ideal, but wth.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but unfortunately re-cloning doesn't help. The moment after, it still thinks it needs to be cloned.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem for many years and VS versions. But last night, working with VS 2017 Enterprise v15.7.5 I found that for me, the only way VS recognized correctly the already existing repo is when it has a remote named "origin". So every pull/push etc Will be done from Visual Studio to the server referenced by that name.
In this case, the integration works really great! If you need to change the name of your remote, one alternative is to edit the file .git/config.
A possible solution here from Visual Studio part, will be allowing to select the already existing remote you want to work with.